# destroy a one-to-one relationship in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a relationship like the one in doctrine's docs so i'll use it as an example:

```
Product:
  type: entity
  oneToOne:
    shipping:
      targetEntity: Shipping
      joinColumn:
        name: shipping_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

I'm attempting to delete a `Shipping` entity but am getting a foreign key constraint exception because the `Product`'s row holds a reference to it. What's the proper way of handling this? Is there something in the yaml that i can add to take care of this? Or do i need to do something like below:

```
$product->setShipping(null);
$entityManager->persist($product);
$entityManager->remove($shipping);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Comment: Did you try to just do `$em->remove($shipping); $em->flush();` without setting shipping to `null` on product?

Comment: @igor yes i did. Got the foreign key constraint exception

Answer (score 0):

You should set the `onDelete` option to *CASCADE* if you want the `Shipping` to be removed too, or to *SET NULL* if you want to delete just the `Product`.

```
Product:
  type: entity
  oneToOne:
    shipping:
      targetEntity: Shipping
      joinColumn:
        name: shipping_id
        referencedColumnName: id
        onDelete: "SET NULL"
```

You can read more about this on the [Doctrine docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html?highlight=onDelete#removing-entities).

Comment: i'm not trying to delete the project at all. I still want it to exist. Where did you read about `"SET NULL"`?

Comment: I'm sorry, in that case you should put the `onDelete` in the Shipping entity. I didn't see *SET NULL* in the docs, but I already knew it existed. It's a MySQL behavior.

Comment: in the shipping entity, on the same level as the `type` key in the yaml?

Comment: @Isouza here's my yaml. I've highlighted the entity i'm trying to delete without deleting the owning entity https://gist.github.com/dadamssg/d56a28fc4872897518a2#file-requestmatcher-orm-yml-L63

Comment: have you tried the "SET NULL" approach on the `activeResponse` entity? it's the only way I know.